# Pass data from node.js to sql query

Tags: mysql, node.js

I've got some code for testing here:

```
bot.on('message', (msg) => {
    if (msg.text[3] === '#') {
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Added to DB, thanks!", {});
        connection.query('INSERT INTO botrequests (places_count, discount_count) VALUES (msg.text, msg.text)',
            function (error, results, fields) {
                if (error) throw error;
                console.log("Success");
            });
    }
})
```

What I wanna do is to insert msg.text twice into a table botrequests in columns places_count and discount_count.
Tried using ' ' and " " but this never helped. What's the right way to pass a variable into a query statement?

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass values to your query, use bind parameters

```js
connection.query('INSERT INTO botrequests (places_count, discount_count) VALUES (?, ?)',
    [msg.text, msg.text],
    function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log("Success");
    });
```

See [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values)

Comment: You made my day!

Comment: that's great  @lesha_ber ! Remember to set up as a correct answer if it answered your question